# Flash Professional project - font gets cut

Tags: flash, flash-builder, textfield, embedding

I have a problem with embedding fonts in my Flash Professional Project. I just recently upgraded from CS5.5 to Creative Cloud, so now I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 and Flash CC. My project has been working fine until the upgrade. I used TLFTextField for some of the text in my AIR application, but when I converted my files to Flash CC they got replaced with regular TextField's.

This shouldn't be a problem for me since I'm not using specific TLF features anymore. However now special characters like ÅÄÖ gets cut off (embedded font Gotham Black).

It looks like this: 
http://s2.postimg.org/t3dm1mu9l/cut_text.png

Could it be the font since it worked with TLFTextField?

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

since tlf is removed from CC some characters (unicode mostly) got problems. best suggestion is to keep an earlier version of flash installed and use it to make tlf texts then import them as swf files.